# Create a Custom Android Plugin: java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

Tags: ionic-framework, plugman

I´m developing this Android application to run on device.
I´m using Ionic and Angular to develop the application.

Now I need to create a custom plugin using Plugman. This plugin should allowed user to authentication using IBM APP ID.

I followed the instructions mention here https://github.com/ibm-cloud-security/appid-clientsdk-android
to create my gradle file.

However, when I run ionic cordova run android --verbose --debug
I get this error

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task :app:processDebugManifest.

> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

And I have no clue what could be the root cause. This is my first time I develop a custom plugin.
My suspicious relies on the dependency, but I can not tell what part is causing the issue.

````
Ionic Framework : @ionic/angular 5.0.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.26
@angular-devkit/schematics : 8.3.26
@angular/cli : 8.3.26
@ionic/angular-toolkit : 2.2.0

Cordova:

Cordova CLI : 10.0.0
Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 7 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res (update available: 0.14.0) : 0.10.0
native-run (update available: 1.0.0) : 0.3.0

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\\Android\\sdk)
NodeJS : v14.2.0 (C:\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe)
npm : 6.14.4
OS : Windows 10```

LOG=======================================
C:\project_cren\plugin\ci-uix-mobile-master>ionic cordova run android --verbose --debug
  ionic:lib Terminal info: { ci: false, shell: 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe', tty: false, windows: true } +0ms
  ionic:lib CLI global options: { _: [ 'cordova', 'run', 'android' ], help: null, h: null, verbose: true, quiet: null, interactive: false, color: true, confirm: null, json: null, debug: true, project: null, '--': [] } +4ms
  ionic:lib:project Project type from config: @ionic/angular (angular) +0ms
  ionic:lib:project Project details: { configPath: 'C:\\project_cren\\plugin\\ci-uix-mobile-master\\ionic.config.json', errors: [], context: 'app', type: 'angular' } +1ms
  ionic Context: { binPath: 'C:\\Users\\AMANDODOSSANTOSNETO\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@ionic\\cli\\bin\\ionic', libPath: 'C:\\Users\\AMANDODOSSANTOSNETO\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@ionic\\cli', execPath: 'C:\\project_cren\\plugin\\ci-uix-mobile-master', version: '6.7.0' } +0ms
  ionic:lib:integrations:cordova:config Loading Cordova Config (config.xml: 'C:\\project_cren\\plugin\\ci-uix-mobile-master\\config.xml', package.json: 'C:\\project_cren\\plugin\\ci-uix-mobile-master\\package.json') +0ms
  ionic:commands:run Native platform devices: [] +0ms
  ionic:lib:integrations:cordova:config Loading Cordova Config (config.xml: 'C:\\project_cren\\plugin\\ci-uix-mobile-master\\config.xml', package.json: 'C:\\project_cren\\plugin\\ci-uix-mobile-master\\package.json') +11s
  ionic:lib:build build options: {
  ionic:lib:build   '--': [],
  ionic:lib:build   engine: 'cordova',
  ionic:lib:build   platform: 'android',
  ionic:lib:build   project: 'app',
  ionic:lib:build   verbose: false,
  ionic:lib:build   configuration: undefined,
  ionic:lib:build   sourcemaps: undefined,
  ionic:lib:build   cordovaAssets: true,
  ionic:lib:build   watch: undefined,
  ionic:lib:build   type: 'angular'
  ionic:lib:build } +0ms
  ionic:lib:hooks Looking for ionic:build:before npm script. +0ms
  ionic:lib:build Looking for ionic:build npm script. +154ms
  ng:analytics getGlobalAnalytics +0ms
  ng:analytics Client Analytics config found: false +47ms
  ng:analytics Analytics disabled. Ignoring all analytics. +1ms
  ng:analytics getSharedAnalytics +0ms
  
  
  
  
  WARNING in ./src/app/invoice-detail/invoice-detail.component.scss
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Warning

(4:3) start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead
 @ ./src/app/invoice-detail/invoice-detail.component.ts 27:41-83
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
  ionic:lib:hooks Looking for ionic:build:after npm script. +40s

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
C:\project_cren\plugin\ci-uix-mobile-master\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd build android --debug --verbose exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: 'process.exit' received +0ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: running 2 functions +1ms
  ionic:utils-process error while killing process tree for 17344: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 17344 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERROR: The process "17344" not found.
  ionic:utils-process 
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:303:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5) {
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 17344 /T /F'
  ionic:utils-process } +472ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: error from function: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 17344 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERROR: The process "17344" not found.
  ionic:utils-process 
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:303:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5) {
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 17344 /T /F'
  ionic:utils-process } +21ms
  ionic:utils-process error while killing process tree for 2628: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 2628 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERROR: The process "2628" not found.
  ionic:utils-process 
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:303:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5) {
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 2628 /T /F'
  ionic:utils-process } +40ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: error from function: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 2628 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERROR: The process "2628" not found.
  ionic:utils-process 
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:303:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5) {
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 2628 /T /F'
  ionic:utils-process } +8ms
  ionic:utils-process processExit: exiting (exit code: 1) +4ms

GRADLE FILE=====================================================================
android {
    //compileSdkVersion 29
    //buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
       manifestPlaceholders = ['appIdRedirectScheme': android.defaultConfig.applicationId]
    }
}

dependencies {
   implementation 'com.github.ibm-cloud-security:appid-clientsdk-android:6.+'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

JAVA FILE ==============================================
package ibm.com.ibmappidcordovaplugin;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.ibm.cloud.appid.android.api.AppID;
import com.ibm.cloud.appid.android.api.AuthorizationException;
import com.ibm.cloud.appid.android.api.AuthorizationListener;
import com.ibm.cloud.appid.android.api.LoginWidget;
import com.ibm.cloud.appid.android.api.tokens.AccessToken;
import com.ibm.cloud.appid.android.api.tokens.IdentityToken;
import com.ibm.cloud.appid.android.api.tokens.RefreshToken;

/**
 * This class echoes a string called from JavaScript.
 */
public class ibmappidcordovaplugin extends CordovaPlugin {
    //PluginResult result = null;
    private CallbackContext callbackContext = null;
    private static final String SHOW_AUTH = "authentication";
    LoginWidget loginWidget;
    loginWidget = AppID.getInstance().getLoginWidget();

    public ibmappidcordovaplugin(){
        AppID.getInstance().initialize(getApplicationContext(), "cdb1c3ab-e8cf-49cf-9dff-9dfa4bf2a898", AppID.REGION_US_SOUTH);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        this.callbackContext = callbackContext;
        String msg = args.getJSONObject(0).getString("msg");
        if (action.equals("authentication")) {
            //String message = args.getString(0);
            this.coolMethod(msg, callbackContext);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void coolMethod(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {
            auth();
            callbackContext.success(create());
        } else {
            callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
        }
    }

    private void auth(){
        loginWidget.launch(this, new AuthorizationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAuthorizationSuccess(final AccessToken accessToken, final IdentityToken identityToken,
                                               RefreshToken refreshToken) {
                
                cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       
                        console.log("Name: " + identityToken.getName());
                        console.log("user: " + accessToken.getScope());
                        console.log("getIdentities " + identityToken.getIdentities());
                        console.log("getRaw " + identityToken.getRaw());

                        for (String name : identityToken.getAudience() ) {
                            console.log("AUD: " +name);
                        }

                        for (String name : identityToken.getAuthenticationMethods() ) {
                            console.log("AUTH: " +name);
                        }

                        try {
                            JSONObject ob = identityToken.getPayload();

                            console.log("getPayload " + ob.getString("preferred_username"));
                        }
                        catch (Exception e){
                            console.log("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthorizationCanceled() {
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthorizationFailure (AuthorizationException exception) {
                
                
            }
        });
    }

    private String create(/*IdentityToken identityToken*/){
        String response = "";
        try {
            JSONObject token = new JSONObject();
            String t = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6ImFwcElkLWNkYjFjM2FiLWU4Y2YtNDljZi05ZGZmLTlkZmE0YmYyYTg5OC0yMDIwLTA5LTI1VDE1OjE5OjI4LjIxNyIsInZlciI6NH0.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.C4_2mj3fx3IwfqH4_O8CR4NtSNpgR7WTbjOz9j1XvrAZS9uiTswMyCn9q8N8pIh6BuP2RTmBhAtnkjAYt0rkHOtEHutf9J79GkpN33-H5P-5k9pqopUuawyFZlfEuH3m76PVnH2XkDUZ1EOTRKrtuHIyYS74tGOYgF8r3hBwjSbFZPTchkNAQmqn5FTgJ6LzUa3xBWt3C1nkvMw3nKrorAUtrsCZXD9PGJKlqJhpZXH9renSRa4KDDwswHzhLGiIghgAmvVoNwOsUWrWbQF88EGDKAkyQRCnTRo2lqdANtYlIwsVitGc9zkje6wDOhjjfZ6g24sj9Id-kK7Sw813aQ";
            token.put("name", "Fulando da Silva"/*identityToken.getName()*/);
            token.put("email", "fulano@test.com"/*identityToken.getEmail()*/);
            token.put("token", t/*identityToken.getRaw()*/);
            response = token.toString();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return response;
    }
}
````

Comment: You don't give much information, it's hard to help here. I developed a cordova ionic plugin a year ago and it was not easy to make it work, so I wrote a post with the instructions, maybe it helps you: https://joangape.blogspot.com/2019/11/create-custom-cordova-plugin-for-ionic4.html. 
The biggest difficulty is not the plugin itself, but the connection to Ionic. Good luck!

Comment: if you can share your Plugin Repo it will be better.

Comment: Sorry, the code belongs to my company, I shall not.

Comment: @elnezah, what kind of information do you need?
First, I develop a simple plugin to receive and send text information. That worked as expected. I install the plugin on my Ionic project using the plugman install and tested successfully on my android device.
Using the same plugin and changing the java code to add the app id code and create the gradle file to add the dependencies.

Again I uninstall and install the plugin, which is done just fine. However, where I run the ionic cordova run android is where I get the error.

Comment: @elnezah, 
I just read your article I did followed some of the step when I first create this test plugin. But, as I mentioned, I can not move forward due to java nullpointexception during  ionic cordova run android.